# Firebase Messaging token not generated for Debug build

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In release build FCM token is generated.

In debug, getting this error -

```
response: [403 Forbidden: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from this Android client application com.example.app are blocked.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_ANDROID_APP_BLOCKED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "consumer": "projects/381175343517",
          "service": "firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```

> E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate
> with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update
> your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options
> (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.

This is how i have set it up -

1. Created my android project in Firebase with Release SHA-1
2. In https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/ I have restricted Auto generated key
   to be used with my App only, provided Release SHA-1 with app package name.
3. API restrictions: selected 'Don't restrict key'
4. Enabled FirebaseInstalltions

Using this piece of code to get FCM token -

```
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful && it.result != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Token generated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Token not generated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
```

What i have tried so far -

- Deleted auto-generated build (and values.xml file) directory when changing the key.
- Setting up with FirebaseOptions
- Release build (It works)
- Provided my debug SHA-1 also in Android apps restriction, it works then, but if i have
  more than 20 people working on this app, do they all have to provide their debug SHA-
  1? I don't think it's good.
- If i remove app restriction for API (release SHA-1), then it works
  for Debug and Release both. But i want to restrict it for my app
  only.

Expected result:

- Token should generated for both release and debug builds

Autual result:

- Token not generating for Debug build.

Please help, i have tried all the available resouces about this issue and even related issues.

Let me know if i need to provide any other info.
Thank you!

Comment: I have been using the Api key for my app for a long time, and until recently everything worked perfectly, but about a month ago problems started with Firebase installations: "code": 403 "API_KEY_ANDROID_APP_BLOCKED". I want to thank you, I removed all restrictions and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

In Android studio's terminal use this command to generate a debug keystore.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp_debug_android.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -dname "C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug"
```

Where `myapp_debug_android.keystore` is the file name.

Then in your app's gradle file use this keystore for debug signingConfigs :

```
signingConfigs {

        release {
             ... release config
        }

        debug {
            storeFile file('../myapp_debug_android.keystore')
        }
    }
```

This will keep your debug build hash (SHA) same on any system.

Comment: If it works, please mark it as right answer @User7788. Happy coding!!